# Multiplication of checkbox values not working (jQuery/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have values assigned to checkboxes that tally up in a read-only textbox (Running CPC Total), and this works.

I then have a textbox for the user to enter number of clicks, and a JS function multiplies the Running CPC Total value with this number of clicks value to give a Total Cost, which is displayed in another read-only textbox (Total Cost). This also works.

My issue is when I get to the agency discount checkboxes. What should happen is that if the 10% checkbox is selected (for example), both of the aforementioned read-only textboxes will have their values multiplied by 0.9 (to achieve a 10% discount). My JS function works for the Running CPC Total, but I'm not sure whats happening with the Total Cost textbox, as it doesn't seem to be taking a discount off.

Can anyone help me as to what is going on? I think I need a fresh perspective on this, I've been racking my brain the last few nights over this.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ud153qot/#&togetherjs=cjayM362sc

The main JS function starts on line 174 of JS fiddle, but will include it below too:

```
//code to update CPC Total when agency discount is applied
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });

  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    var noc = parseFloat($('input[id="numberofclickstextbox"]').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
    var CPCsum = parseFloat($('#sum').val());
    $('#totalcost').val(function() {
      return (noc * CPCsum * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Just change field "number of clicks" you created. What exactly is not working?

Comment: yeah it works, but when you switch between agency discounts the calculations are off - they're not 10% and 15%? If you manually do the calculation (number of clicks * running CPC total * 0.9 or 0.85) they're not correct?